# Have a picture on the right of a section title in ConTeXt

Tags: graphics, positioning, context, wrap

I am trying to set a picture to the right of a section title. Like this (bad ASCII-Art rendering):

```
1.2 Section Title           +---------+
                            | Picture |
Lorem Ipsum                 +---------+
```

So far, I found the `\starthanging` command, which curiously exists but is not documented in the wiki at all, although several posts on this site describe it and refer to the wiki.

I tried this:

```
\section{Section Title}
\starthanging[right]{\tikz{\node[rectangle,draw]{picture};}}
  Lorem Ipsum
\stophanging
```

This works, but puts the picture below the section title. So I tried this instead:

```
\starthanging[right]{\tikz{\node[rectangle,draw]{picture};}}
  \section{Section Title}

  Lorem Ipsum
\stophanging
```

Now the picture just vanishes without a trace. So I tried an alternative approach:

```
\defineparagraphs[sectionandpicture][n=2]

\startsectionandpicture
  \section{Section Title}
\sectionandpicture
  \raggedleft
  \tikz{\node[rectangle,draw]{picture};}
\stopsectionandpicture

Lorem Ipsum
```

This works, but shifts all the text after the heading below the picture. Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: Why not put the picture in the margin?  I don't think that you can do the hanging next to the section title without extensive hacking of the core macros.

Comment: @HenriMenke I will try that, I'm not sure that every picture I use fits there.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get side floats at a section title you have to change the value for the `aligntitle` key to `float`.

```
\usemodule [visual]

\useMPlibrary [dum]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [aligntitle=float]

\showframe

\starttext

\startplacefigure [location={right,none}]
  \externalfigure [dummy] [width=0.3\textwidth,height=5\lineheight]
\stopplacefigure

\startsection [title=\fakewords{4}{6}]
  \fakewords{60}{100}
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image: Side float at a section title]

Comment: This works in general and I will accept it as answer. However, it does not work when the content of the section starts with `{\bf whatever}` for some reason.

Comment: @flyx When you use side floats with paragraphs which starts with a font switch you have to add `\dontleavehmode` at the begin of the paragraph, e.g. `\dontleavehmode{\bf ...} ...`.

Comment: @flyn: Or you `\bold{whatever}`.

Comment: @flyx Never start a paragraph with a group.  That is a well known problem because TeX will happily insert the contents of `\everypar` inside this group, reverting the effects when the group is over.

Comment: @Aditya Please undelete your answer.  It might not be the optimal solution in this case but might be a viable (if not the only) solution in another.

Answer (score 3):

**Wolfgang's solution is the right way to go. I am leaving my older answer here in case someone in a slightly different situation finds this useful.**

If you are willing to do some manual tweaks, then the you can use a side float *after* the section title and move the figure a few lines above. If the section title is large, then you will have to manually break it using `\\`.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]
\usemodule[visual]

\showframe

\starttext
\startsection[title=\fakewords{4}{6}]
  \startplacefigure[location={right,none,-3*line}]
    \externalfigure[dummy][width=0.3\textwidth,height=5\lineheight]
  \stopplacefigure

  \fakewords{60}{100}
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

[image]